# How to programatically force .eml file to open in Outlook or allow to save from browser from Client Web application?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, attachment, exchangewebservices

I have a console application which processes Exchange mailbox. I am storing attachments that comes with emails in Database as HUGEBLOB using bytes of array. Similarly if an attachment is email attachment I'm storing it's MIMEContent as a bytes of array and filename having .eml extension.

Now I am displaying this attachments in another web application. While clicking on .eml file from application It directly opens MIMEContent in web browser. Is there any way I can open it in Outlook as an email message? It is not even allowing me to save locally? How to get that 'Do you want to save or open file?' dialog box that we usually get while clicking on attachments from browser. Is there any way to force this programmatically?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

EML files are not natively handled by Outlook.  Users will have to change the application file handler via a hack outlined here: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/open-eml-files-in-outlook/.